# Large attachments not getting sent in mail in .NET

Tags: asp.net

I am using VS2010 and am trying to send large files with more than 2MB. But the files are not getting sent. Small files easily get sent.

My machine OS is indow server 2008.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Check your web.config file for **maxRequestLength** parameter.

In this case, 2048 = 2 BMB

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2048" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compress your attachment

link : http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csZipEntryRef.html

Sample

```
ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
newEntry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
newEntry.Size = fileData.Length;
```